# jquery mouseover an image to swap another image in the div above

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseover

I would like to add `"-h.png"` to the end of all img src in `< div id="swap" >` at the same time when mouseover/hover over `< img src="images/logo.png" />` and return back to `".png"` mouseout

This is what I have and it's not working:

```
<div id="header-wrap">
    <div id="swap">
        <img src="images/4.png"/>
        <img src="images/3.png"/>
        <img src="images/2.png"/>
        <img src="images/1.png"/>
    </div>
    <header id="header">
        <div id="site-logo"><a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" /></a></div>
    </header>
</div><!-- /#header-wrap --> 

$(document).ready(function() {     
    $('#site-logo').hover(function(){     
        $('#swap img').replace('.png','-h.png');    
    },     
    function(){    
        $('#swap img').replace('-h.png','.png');     
    });
});
```

Just updated to below... the images are swapping now but all 4 images swapped to /4-h.png instead of 4-h.png, 3-h.png, 2-h.png and 1-h.png

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var newSrc = "";
    $('#site-logo').hover(function(){
        newSrc = $('#swap img').attr('src').replace('.png','-h.png');   
        $('#swap img').attr('src', newSrc);
    },     
    function(){
        newSrc = $('#swap img').attr('src').replace('-h.png','.png');     
        $('#swap img').attr('src', newSrc);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
    /* so it's not working
    $(document).ready(function() {     
        $('#site-logo').hover(function(){     
            $('#swap img').attr('src').replace('.png','-h.png');    
        },     
        function(){    
            $('#swap img').attr('src').replace('-h.png','.png');     
        });
    });
    */
```

---

ok so I figured out the .replace method is pure a javascript
try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var newSrc = "";
    $('#site-logo').hover(function(){
        $('#swap img').each(function() {
           newSrc = $(this).attr('src').replace('.png','-h.png');   
           $(this).attr('src', newSrc);
        });
    },     
    function(){
        $('#swap img').each(function() {
           newSrc = $(this).attr('src').replace('-h.png','.png');     
           $(this).attr('src', newSrc);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This is sorta working, the images are swapping now but all 4 images are swapping to 4-h.png instead of 4-h.png, 3-h.png, 2-h.png and 1-h.png

Comment: i didnt realize that you have 4 images..so i edit it with each loop.should be working now

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one just use `.slice()` this way and you can achieve your goal:

```
$('#site-logo').hover(function () {
   var atr = $('#swap img').attr('src').slice(0, -4);
   var newAtr = atr+'-h.png'
   $('#swap img').attr('src', newAtr);
},function () {
   var atr = $('#swap img').attr('src').slice(0, -6);
   var newAtr = atr+'.png'
   $('#swap img').attr('src', newAtr);
});
```

checkout the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6vqJV/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
    $('#site-logo').hover(function(){     
        $('#swap img').attr('src','-h.png');    
    },     
    function(){    
        $('#swap img').attr('src','.png');     
    });
});
```

OR

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
        $('#site-logo').hover(function(){     
            $('#swap img').each(function(){
$(this).attr('src','-h.png');
             });    
        },     
        function(){    
            $('#swap img').each(function(){
$(this).attr('src','.png');
});
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#site-logo").hover(function () {

  $("#swap img").each(function () {
    var test = $(this).attr('src');
    $("#helper").append("<span>" + test.replace('.png', '-h.png') + "</span><br />");
  });

},

function () {
  $("#swap img").each(function () {
    var test = $(this).attr('src');
    $("#helper2").append("<span>" + test.replace('-h.png', '.png') + "</span><br />");
  });

});
```

[Test Link](http://jsfiddle.net/GmRTZ/3/)